# How to cast a Decimal to an int E6

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to construct a `GeoPoint` from 2 `Decimal`. The issue I am facing is the GeoPoint constructor expects 2 ints in E6 format. So with literals it is easy:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)61.54367E6, (int)-149.768E6);
```

But if my inputs are stored as `Decimal` what do I do?

```
Decimal Latitude = 61.54367;
Decimal Longitude = -149.768;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Latitude * 1E6), (int)(Longitude * 1E6));
```

Answer (score 1):

The "E6" format you're talking about is *scientific notation*. It's how floating point literals are written. See §9.4.4.2 (Integer Literals) and §9.4.4.3 (Real Literals) of the C# Standard: ISO/IEC 23270 (Information technology — Programming languages — C#). ISO/IEC 23270 and its brother, ISO/IEC 23271, describing the CLR, are freely available as PDF files from the ISO at

http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html

But all you have to do is cast your `decimal` values to `double`

```
new GeoPoint( (double) latitude , (double) longitude ) ;
```

Or, alternatively, use the static `Decimal.ToDouble()` method:

```
new GeoPoint( Decimal.ToDouble(latitude) , Decimal.ToDouble(longitude) ) ;
```

Makes no difference which you do. The same thing happens under the covers.

You should note, though, that you may lose precision in the conversion to double. `decimal` trades range (magnitude) for precision; `double` and `float` trade precision for range (magnitude). Also, the conversion from `double` to `decimal` will throw an `OverflowException` if the value being converted cannot be represented as a `decimal`.

Any of the following values will throw an `OverflowException`:

- `Double.NaN`
- `Double.PositiveInfinity`
- `Double.NegativeInfinity`
- values less than `Decimal.MinValue`
- values greater than `Decimal.MaxValue`